# Current between RC and RL parts of a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I got stuck on a problem, and I've found the source of my confusion but can't figure out. Cutting to the chase: in the following circuit, the behavior when the switch on the bottom is closed makes complete sense to me, the capacitor being an open circuit and the inductor being a short.

[image]

However, when the switch is opened the current between the RC and the RL part immediately goes to 0, and I can't figure out why. The exact values on the capacitor and inductor don't seem to matter, this stems from a problem where no values are specified. More readable circuit from the original problem below.

[image]

[image]

If anyone has any input on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "the behavior when the switch on the bottom is closed makes complete sense to me, the capacitor being an open circuit and the inductor being a short." you don't mean the moment the switch is closed, but rather when the switch has been closed for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just give an intuitive answer to see if it helps.

- Both the RC and LC blocks have only two "ports". That means that if current goes in one port it must come out the other.
- No current can flow in or out of the outer ports because the circuit loop is open at the switch. That means that no current can flow in the link between the two blocks.
- Anything can happen within each two-port block without charge entering or leaving the block. In this case C will discharge its stored energy (\$\frac 1 2 CV^2\$) through its R and L will discharge its stored energy (\$\frac 1 2 LI^2\$) through its R.

> However, when the switch is opened the current between the RC and the RL part immediately goes to 0,

Correct.

> The exact values on the capacitor and inductor don't seem to matter, ...

Correct - although it does determine the decay time constant, \$ \tau _{RC} = RC \$ and \$ \tau _{RL} = \frac L R \$, of the current and voltage within those loops.

---

From the comments:

> I got stuck in analyzing this based on discharge behavior/equations, and thinking why the capacitor and inductor immediately would have the same voltage on each side of the bridge to make ΔV=0, but maybe unnecessarily so.

I didn't cover the voltages in the circuit as your question was primarily about the currents.

[image]

- In the steady state we have 2.6 V across the CR circuit. When the switch opens we will still have 2.6 V across that pair and this will start to decay with \$ \tau = RC = 1k \times 10\mu = 10\ \text{ms} \$. (After 10 ms the voltage will have decreased by 63%, at 3τ by 95% and 5τ by 99%.)
- Because you have an ideal inductor (zero resistance) the steady-state voltage on the LR circuit will be zero. When you open the switch the inductor tries to keep 2.5 mA flowing through it and the only path for this to take is through the parallel resistor. Notice now that there is a voltage drop across L as the current is no longer constant. Note also that the voltage across R is reversed compared to that on the capacitor circuit.
- The inductor loop time constant is given by \$ \tau = \frac LR = \frac 1 {1k} = 1\ \text{ms} \$. The voltage drop across that resistor will decay at ten times the rate of the other one.
- Interestingly, the voltage across the switch will vary as the capacitor and inductor discharge until after some time<sup>1</sup> it will settle at the battery voltage.

<sup>1</sup> After 5τ of the longer of the two time constants we should be within 1% of the long-term steady-state value.

---

Tip: always include the component designators, R1, R2, etc. It makes it much easier to discuss "R1" rather than "the resistor on the left".

Comment: I think I may have gotten stuck in the weeds of thinking about transient behavior unnecessarily here. I guess what's driving the current when the switch is closed is the voltage source, but when the voltage source is out of play both "sides of the bridge" are the same node and the potential must be equal, making current across impossible.

Comment: Ran out of time to add: Is that kind of all that needs to be said about this? I got stuck in analyzing this based on discharge behavior/equations, and thinking why the capacitor and inductor immediately would have the same voltage on each side of the bridge to make ΔV=0, but maybe unnecessarily so. Thanks for taking the time to answer either way.

Comment: That you for accepting my answer. See if the update addresses your comments.